# enable iframe's design mode

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i have an iframe and in javascript i enable the design mode as follows

```
iframe.contentDocument.designMode="on";
```

which works fine if i create my iframe inline. but if i load my iframe with a "src" attribute in my parent page and i turn on the design mode as follows:

```
iframes=document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for(iframe in iframes)
{
iframes[iframe].contentDocument.designMode="on";
}
```

then it doesnot work. how can i enable the iframe's design mode from the container page if im loading the iframe specifying the src attribute? not inline!!
Thanks

Comment: Are you loading the iframe's contents from the same domain as the parent/containing site? If it's from a different site you will have no access to the DOM of the iframe.

Comment: yea im loading it from the same domian...and still i cant modify the contentDocument properties of the loaded iframe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on the browser, there are a couple of potential issues:

- not all browsers (particularly older ones) support `contentDocument`
- `for...in` is not guaranteed to work on a `NodeList`, which is what `getElementsByTagName()` returns. Use `for` loop instead.
- you may need to wait for all of the iframes to load. The main document's `load` event will fire only once all the iframes have loaded.

Otherwise, so long as the iframe is served from the same domain, it is possible to set its document's `designMode` property from the containing document. The following should work:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for (var i = 0, len = iframes.length, doc; i < len; ++i) {
        doc = iframes[i].contentDocument || iframes[i].contentWindow.document;
        doc.designMode = "on";
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you so much tim..it works. your third point was the problem. i was setting the iframes content document properties at the same time when the iframes were loading. hence they were overriden by the src documents default properties...although i dint get why i shud not use for in loop?

Comment: @Salman: `NodeList` is a host object, which is an object provided by the environment (in this case, the browser). Other host objects include `document`, elements and text nodes. Host objects aren't subject to the same rules as native JavaScript and can essentially do what they like. http://jsfiddle.net/QCPvy/